# Pixel-wise classification of black & white high resolution images

Tags: classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I know of methods using CNNs with fully connected conditional random fields as additional interpolation, or fully convolutional networks which seem to be brutally slow. So I do not want to use these methods because my images are fairly simple (2 pixel values, maybe 20 at most if it turns out that black and white isn't enough, and 10-20 classes for each pixel).

The only issue is that images are fairly high resolution (millions of pixels), so I assume I'd have to use GPU to get performance.

What would be the direction here?

Comment: Pixel-wise classification is known as **image segmentation**. More importantly, what is it that you are actually asking for? What makes you think that FCNs are "brutally slow"? How is input size related to the need of using a GPU? If the task is simple but you feel computation is the bottleneck, why using neural networks in the first place?

Comment: Well, I've seen several image segmentation papers and I found the inference and training slow. However most segmentation papers, due to the nature of CNNs, have an interpolation part to achieve pixel precision. My task is most definitely requiring pixel percision as shapes are much more smaller than shapes are in common image segmentation tasks.

My intuition tells me if I have to do millions of inferences on CPU (for a single image) it's going to get pretty slow, even slower than FCNs.

Comment: fully convolutional architectures only do a single forward pass to make predictions on the millions of pixels in an image -- you don't need to do millions of inferences, just one. here is some work on 30 fps segmentation with high res inputs (although admittedly with a gpu) https://eccv2018.org/openaccess/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Hengshuang_Zhao_ICNet_for_Real-Time_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf